# SQL, only returning rows where at least one more entry with the same value in one column is found

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry if my wording is really bad. I'm not very good with remembering the terms just yet.

I have something like the following (and I can't make any changes to it):

> Books(BookID, Title)
>
> Author(BookID, WritID)
>
> Writer(WritID, FirstName, LastName)

I want to be able to list the books by title who have more than one author, as the authors are set out something like this:

> Book01, Dude01
>
> Book02, Dude01
>
> Book02, Dude02

I've been trying to use `COUNT` and `HAVING` to get the duplicates and `JOIN` to connect Books and Author but I've got a feeling the following is **completely** off. :(

```
select Title, BookID, count(*)
from Author
join Books
on Author.BookID=Books.BookID
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Any help or point in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which database system is it?

Comment: @Szymon Ah, sorry. Um.. Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `GROUP BY` - you need to group by all the columns you want to see in the results that are not aggregated:

```
select Books.Title, Books.BookID, count(*)
from Author
join Books
on Author.BookID=Books.BookID
group by Books.Title, Books.BookID
having count(*) >= 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebb1a/1)

Comment: I just tried that and I got `ERROR at line 5: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry. I pressed enter before I finished typing. I edited it now.

Answer (score 3):

For aggregated functions, use Group By clause.

The SQL GROUP BY Clause can be used in a SQL SELECT query to collect data across multiple records and group the results by one or more columns.

Comment: Ah, I understand. All I had up until now was a very rudimentary understand of `GROUP BY`, so thank you for explaining how it works. :)